# Can you control the latency for java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, latency

I'm creating a tiny server that will always listen for new connections. About 30 times a second the server will "wake up" and send an update request to a client. The client will be asleep until it's time to wake up (as established by the last connection) and accept the request and fire off the update. Because the window for the exchange is going to consistently be small, how do I manage the latency of the sleep thread to get a more accurate and precise measurement of sleep cycles?

Comment: This client, does it need to read the data in the exact moment, the data is received by the network interface? You mean to even guess the network latency. Btw, if your client has an open socket where the server sends to, the server will be able to send data even if the client thread (that one, that reads the socket) is asleep. What is the real deal here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

What you have here is 2 *absolutely different* activities coupled together. 
One is responsible for periodical wakeups and the other takes care of updating the client.
If the wakeup task *waits* for update task to be done then its accuracy will suffer.

What you can do is solve the problem by introducing some degree of asynchrony into your server.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    final Runnable notificationTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            updater.sendUpdate();                          // just *notify* the updater to do an update
        }
    };

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        notificationTask, 0, 33333333, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS // freakishly accurate :)
    );
```

Comment: I see. This would work thank you. I was using Executors anywho, apparently just never noticed the scheduledPool :P.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't it stay awake throughout? Does the [Observer / Observable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern help you in any way?

Comment: It very well could stay awake the whole time, but I'm designing for battery optimization. And I'll look that Observer currently.

Comment: Just evaluate that by sleeping and waking up 30 times a second you're not wasting resources rather than saving them.